# Setting external application focus

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In VB.NET, you can set focus to an external application using

```vb
AppActivate("Windows Name")
```

or

```vb
AppActivate(processID As Integer)
```

Now this works fine if you do for example:

```vb
Dim intNotePad As Integer = Shell("C:\WINNT\Notepad.exe",
AppWinStyle.MinimizedNoFocus)
AppActivate(intNotePad)
```

But when I do:

```vb
For Each theprocess As Process In processlist
    If InStr(theprocess.ProcessName, "DWG") Then
        strProcessList += String.Format("Process: {0} ID: {1}", theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id) + vbCrLf
        AppActivate(theprocess.ID)
    End If
Next
```

then it doesn't find the window, even if it's open and even if it finds the window using the window title.

But I need it by process ID.

How can I do that?

I need it to set focus on a 3rd party installer in a windows installer setup project.

Comment: why is this tagged "asp.net"?

Comment: Please, never use `InStr`. `theprocess.ProcessName.Contains("DWG")` is the "correct", .NET way to do things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know exactly why your not achieving the correct result. Generally, when setting focus to other applications, I've never had too much luck with `AppActivate` (varying degrees of success, at least). Try this instead:

Add this class to the same module / object / whereever your code is:

```vb
Public NotInheritable Class Win32Helper
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", _
    EntryPoint:="SetForegroundWindow", _
    CallingConvention:=Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall, _
    CharSet:=Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function _
    SetForegroundWindow(ByVal handle As IntPtr) As Boolean
        ' Leave function empty
    End Function

    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", _
    EntryPoint:="ShowWindow", _
    CallingConvention:=Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall, _
    CharSet:=Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError:=True)> _
    Public Shared Function ShowWindow(ByVal handle As IntPtr, _
    ByVal nCmd As Int32) As Boolean
        ' Leave function empty
    End Function
End Class
```

Then in your code, instead of `AppActivate`, do the following:

```vb
Dim appHandle As intPtr
appHandle = theprocess.MainWindowHandle 'theprocess is naturally your process object

Dim Win32Help As New Win32Helper
Win32Helper.SetForegroundWindow(appHandle)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try these Win32 functions:

```vb
Declare Sub SwitchToThisWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal fAltTab As Boolean)
Declare Function SetActiveWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
Private Enum ShowWindowEnum
    Hide = 0
    ShowNormal = 1
    ShowMinimized = 2
    ShowMaximized = 3
    Maximize = 3
    ShowNormalNoActivate = 4
    Show = 5
    Minimize = 6
    ShowMinNoActivate = 7
    ShowNoActivate = 8
    Restore = 9
    ShowDefault = 10
    ForceMinimized = 11
End Enum
```

Use `Process.MainWindowHandle` to get the handle. This works on most, but not all, applications.