# How to send keytype to notepad?

Tags: c#, virtual-keyboard

Im playing around in C# and want my little console program to spell my name in a notepad window I have open. I've got the window handle (IntPtr) but don't really know what to do from here.

I could use SendKey but I want it to work whenever the notepad has focus or not, and as I understand it Senkey only work if you have the windowed focused :(

**EDIT:**
I've tried the following (trying to simulate pressing B):

```
PostMessage(NotepadWindowHandle, 0x100, 0x42, 0);
Thread.Sleep(1000);
PostMessage(NotepadWindowHandle, 0x101, 0x42, 0);
```

Nothing happens :( And it does not break

Comment: You can also look into this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922707/setting-external-application-focus Its VB but should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, [`SendKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx) only works for focused windows.

What you want to do is P/Invoke [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and send [`WM_SETTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632644%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the text box's handle (note that that's not the main window handle!). To get it you navigate down the window hierarchy until you reach it with [`GetWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

As a freebie, to get the text box's handle, simply call `GetWindow` with `GW_CHILD` on your main Notepad window handle and you'll get it, it's literally the first child.

Comment: Although note that this doesn't *type* the text. It'll only work for windows that understand WM_SETTEXT.

Comment: Which the Notepad window does.

Comment: ...which the Notepad window does. Because it's an EDIT control. I believe that RichText windows will work, so WordPad's OK too. I'm just making the point that it's not *typing* the text, so it might not work with other text entry fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Notepad’s window handle, why don’t you first activate it as the foreground window and *then* issue your `SendKey`?

This is the P/Invoke signature for setting a window as the foreground window:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

**Edit**: Former answer for a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8953524/1149773