# Make a textbox always have focus

Tags: c#, focus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting external application focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922707/setting-external-application-focus)

even know it DUPLICATE BUT it is different language. Some Pro. Programer will think is easy BUT not for beginner. Which don't have any knowledge about VB.

I'm making this application to check money from a card. It will list all the details pertaining to what they used it for and when. I will set up 1 PC with no keyboard and mouse, and it will automatically boot and shut down every day.

However, there is one problem. For example, I have TeamViewer and this application that I'm making. Both programs will start up when Windows boots. If my application starts up first, the textbox within will lose focus when TeamViewer starts.

I've already tried to use `TopMost` and `ShowDialog`, but when another application starts, the textbox still loses focus.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Set the color to look like focus. Why would you want this?

Comment: On lost focus give it focus again.

Comment: What is your app ? and what is the other app which causes it to lose focus, can you edit and frame a proper question ?

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding about focus. You wrote "another application" the operating system makes sure that only ONE of the many applications running can have the focus, otherwise who would get the keyboard input for example. You have to live with the fact that your application can't and shouldn't have the focus all the time. But if it is about your own application and your other windows, there might be some solution. But even here i strongly advice you not to mess to much with focus handling.

Comment: @Keplah; there's no need to be personal. You can comment as others have and ask for clarification of the question. Down-vote if the question still makes no sense and ultimately flag for a moderator to take a look if you think it warrants it.

Comment: @minitech can u undelete my question ??? i delete my mistake???

Comment: @minitech how to reopen question without create one new?

Comment: @Fuex the program is work fine only i can't make focus all the time can u help me plz?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal i have been try it but it not work

Comment: @V4Vendetta CAN U come read again i already update information

Comment: *Please* don't notify everybody, it doesn't help. I've voted to re-open - it takes five, so you'll need to be patient. Keep updating your question as best you can in the meantime. People will see it.

Comment: @minitech can i delete this Question and reopen it?

Comment: @user1437099: No, and if you do that, the new question will be closed as a duplicate. Again. Keep doing it, and you may find yourself with a question ban, which is *not* a good thing to have :)

Comment: @minitech can i ask u something?? Why my question duplicate even it Code to make it go it some BUT it a different code? it like SQL MYSQL and MSSQL some Convert to Datestring it not some Code is it duplicate  question?

Comment: @user1437099 If this is winform, you can set `ActiveControl` property of the form as the `Textbox`, check out maybe that helps

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use the [`LostFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus.aspx) event and "re-focus" the TextBox:

```
textBox.LostFocus += new EventHandler((s, e) => textBox.Focus());
```

This doesn't work if your form and the parent controls aren't focused.